# How to write SQL query to select percentage with inner join?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two table like

First table

```
FtID         ItemName            Days
---------------------------------------
1            Drive                10
2            Run                  5
3            Read                 21
```

Second Table

```
StID    FtID        Completed (bit)         DateTime  
-----------------------------------------------------

1        1             0                    07/11/2011
2        1             1                    08/11/2011 
3        1             1                    09/11/2011 
4        1             0                    10/11/2011 
5
```

I need to select from both tables and get data like you can see below

```
ItemName Days DaysCompleted DaysIncompleted  PercentageCompletion     DaysLeft
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
Drive     10    2              2                40%                   6
```

Comment: I tried just to join two tables. but it's not working for me when i try to count first var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      t1.ItemName,
      t1.Days,
      SUM(Cast(t2.Completed as integer))  DaysCompleted ,
      COUNT(t2.StID) -  SUM(Cast(t2.Completed as integer)) DaysIncompleted  ,
      (COUNT(t2.StID) * 100 / t1.Days))  PercentageCompletion     ,
      t1.Days - SUM(CASE WHEN DateTime > GetDate() THEN 1 ELSE 0)) DaysLeft
FROM 
     table1 t1 
     INNER JOIN table2 t2
     ON t1.ftId = t2.ftID
GROUP BY
      t1.ItemName,
      t1.Days
```

As JNK noted if Completed is Indeed  a BIT you'll need to cast to an integer (or use SUM/CASE as with his answer). Also I outputted Percentage Complete as `40` if you want `.40` then you'll need to cast to decimal if t1.Days is not already a decimal.

Comment: If the `Completed` field is a `BIT` I don't think you can run a `SUM()` on it directly.

Comment: I did minor changes and it works except the DaysLeft. It shows me the same as days incompleted. I need to return days that not completed and datetime greater then now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   ItemName,
   Days,
   sum(cast(Completed as integer) as DaysCompleted,
   (max(DateTime) - min(DateTime)) - sum(cast(Completed as integer) as Days Incompleted,
   (Days - (max(DateTime) - min(DateTime))) / Days as Percentage Completion,
   Days - (max(DateTime) - min(DateTime)) as DaysLeft
FROM
   Table_1 T1 INNER JOIN Table_2 T2 ON T1.FtID = T2.FtID
GROUP BY
   ItemName,
   Days
```

Start with this / play around with it

Comment: I'm getting error Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: OK -- then use Convert instead of Cast.  (Just F1 it to learn about it, otherwise, it's basically just Convert(datatype, field).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT  f.ItemName, 
        f.Days,
        SUM(CASE WHEN s.Completed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DaysCompleted,
        SUM(CASE WHEN s.completed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DaysIncompleted,
        CAST((COUNT(s.completed)/f.days) as DECIMAL(10,8)) as PercentageComplete,
        (f.days-(COUNT(s.completed)) as DaysLeft
FROM FirstTable F
INNER JOIN SecondTable S
    ON F.FTID = S.FTID
GROUP BY f.itemname, f.days
```